# How do you make a child img show an image?

Tags: javascript, html, child-process

I am trying to make a child element appear when you click a button but the child element is an image but the image won't appear, only the element will. I have recycled some code from a different project and that might be the issue but I'm not too sure.

I originally had the code to create an `<img>` child but then it would say that I couldn't append it. I have tried changing the code to not append the child but that only ends up with another error. (In advance, sorry if the name of the image seems a bit immature but it's named that way to keep myself organized. And sorry if the formatting is off, I'm a bit new to the site.)
Here's the code if you want to check it out;

```
function G() {
    var B1 = src="Intro-v4PPSs.jpg"
    const para = document.createElement("img");
    const node = document.createAttribute(B1);
    para.appendChild(node);
    const element = document.getElementById("demo");
    element.appendChild(para);
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest you add HTML markup and relevant CSS styles as well. Showing/hiding an element can be done in several different ways, and not all involve JavaScript. By the way, your JavaScript statements have syntax errors. (e.g. `B1 = src = "...."`)

Comment: @BumhanYu I tried that already. When I tried it, it left a huge gap between the text and where the image would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function should be like this as below

```js
function G() {
    const para = document.createElement("img");
    para.src = "Intro-v4PPSs.jpg";
    const element = document.getElementById("demo");
    element.appendChild(para);
}
```